# How to add window API for toolbar in Java?

Tags: java, api, user-interface, netbeans, toolbar

I am developing a peice of software that will be a tool.
I am now at analysis phase. But I want to know how can I add some windows toolbars ( like the toolbar that have open/save/print) in my application .
Btw, I'm using Netbeans for coding.
I hope my Question is clear.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's described in [the toolbar section of the Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html).

Comment: That's right but this is not what I need exactly.
I need to just use the windows library or DLL that enable me to use the toolbar that have Open file Button, Save Button,Print Button.

Comment: There's no standard open/save/print toolbar, because not all programs have (just) that functionality. You need to make it yourself using the information from the page I linked. It's pretty simple to add a bar with three buttons.

Comment: Any more help , I want to utilize the operating system property.for example I want to print something.Thanks for your help